# CSS3 drop shadow

Tags: css, dropshadow

I am trying to create an object with a drop shadow.  I believe you need CSS3 to do this and I have something like this so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
div
{
width:300px;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add box shadows:

```
#thediv 
{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; /* firefox shadows*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; /* chrome / safari shadows */
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; /* general browser support */
}​
```

example on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lyubent/BzMey/) but as a note, as this is CSS3 and IE6/7 are old, it will not work with them.

Comment: why do you include the actual css3 box-shadow twice? any reason?

Comment: Where do I include it twice?  Also could you like my question so I could approve your answer.  I am new to this site :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this style into your div tag

```
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; 
/* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
box-shadow: 20px 20px 55px #888888;
```

Comment: you should include the webkit one too really.